# Problematic connectionstring, state closes and opens

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, connection-string

I have a connectionstring in my xamarin android project:

```
`<add name="NewsPushEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ROONEY;Initial Catalog=NewsPush;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`
```

when I first open my project I get the state as closed.

[image]

But when I click to expand the connection in the server explorer it turns green:

[image]

However when I am trying to fetch something in my application by calling the said connectionstring it returns emptyhanded (It's a rest-service returning a menu in Json format, It works when I connect to the live server but not my local one.)

connection to live server:

```
<add name="NewsPushEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=removed;initial catalog=NewsPush;persist security info=True;user id=removed;password=removed;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Last but not least when my state is open (after expanding my connection and it turns green) I get the following properties:

[image]

Did I bum up on the connectionstring somehow? Not sure how to get this to respond. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by empty handed? No errors?

Comment: I get System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused

Comment: Try the same connection string using another tool. It will most certainly not working indicating there may be a problem with the connection e.g. port not open or whatever. I think your network administration guys will be able to help. If you don't have those, check the application logs in the event viewer of the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any errors, debug your service in your local machine and use the watch window to determine if your connection string is correctly set.